# C hello world program is crashing on variable output

Tags: c

To start off, I'm coming off from a c# background, so I do have a knowledge on intermediate programming.

So this is my first C program, and when I try to print the variable "testtt" it crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char testtt = "Hello world";
    //scanf("%s", &test);
    printf(testtt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `char *testtt = "Hello world";` instead

Comment: `const char* testtt = "Hello world";` or `char testtt[] = "Hello world";`

Comment: try compiling with warnings enabled, and you'll get told what's wrong.

Comment: Turn on all the compiler warnings and you'll avoid this and lots more "weird C stuff" you're going to meet as you learn...

Comment: and for the future, never get input from e.g. a user (commented out scanf) and then print it with printf(string_from_user). _Always_ do printf("%s", string_from_user). Otherwise bad things will happen (SIGSEGV) when the user's string contains e.g. "%s".

Comment: @John3136 How do I do this in code::blocks?

Comment: @VillaCaleb No idea. I don't use code::blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` only holds one character. Use `char testtt[] = "Hello world";`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char testtt = "Hello world";
```

to

```
char testtt[] = "Hello world";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the printf should also be:

```
printf("%s", testtt);
```